# Will the wallpaper apps be affected by Google play repetitive content policy?

Tags: android, google-play

Some Google Play dev accounts have published multiple wallpaper apps, where each is identical in design, UI, functionality and features, but differs in content (wallpapers). Each app has content of only one category. The app code is same just the package name and wallpapers are changed in all apps. Apps are like - Car Wallpapers, Flower Wallpapers, Puppy Wallpapers, Kitten wallpapers, Mountain Wallpapers, then do these apps violate the [Google Play Repetitive content policy](https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/spam/repetitive-content/)?

​

Some of them are:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Cute+Live+Wallpapers+And+Backgrounds

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Holiday+Wallpaper

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Los+Angeles+Dream

​

Reference:

https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/spam/repetitive-content/

Comment: Related [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/295004)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question.